# Prevent manual scrolling of a ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a ScrollViewer which wraps a bunch of dynamically created TextBox controls. The `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` are both set to *Hidden*. I am programmatically scrolling the ScrollViewer in response to the user scrolling a gridview.

The problem i am having is that when the user places the focus on one of those TextBox elements and then presses the left/right arrow keys, the ScrollViewer is scrolling. I want to prevent this manual scrolling and only allow programmatic scrolling. Obviously disabling the ScrollViewer is not an option as the user needs to be able to add text to the TextBoxes inside it. Similarly, setting the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property to *Disabled* doesn't work, as that resets the scroll offset back to zero.

How can i lock scrolling, or prevent manual scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

By removing manual operation of the scroll bars, and hiding them, you are basically saying you want something that has a list of items, that can be scrolled from code, but is not a ListBox...

**Conclusion: Don't use a ListBox :)**

As you are managing the scrolling yourself, why not parent the TextBoxes under a StackPanel within a canvas (with a clipping rectangle of course). Then use the Canvas.Top/Left properties on the StackPanel to scroll it.

The example below does that. I added a slider bound to the *Canvas.Top* property so you can test it.

### Xaml Example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.NotAListbox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Canvas Background="Aquamarine" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="200">
            <Canvas.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,200,200"></RectangleGeometry>
            </Canvas.Clip>
            <StackPanel Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" Name="stackPanel1">
                <TextBox Height="23" Text="textBox 1" Width="120" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Text="textBox 2" Width="120" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Text="textBox 3" Width="120" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Text="textBox 4" Width="120" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Text="textBox 5" Width="120" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Text="textBox 6" Width="120" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Text="textBox 7" Width="120" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Text="textBox 8" Width="120" />
                <TextBox Height="23" Text="textBox 9" Width="120" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
        <Slider Height="171" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="316,62,57,66" Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="27" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="-223" Maximum="200" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```